# Simple Double Split

Tags: c#

I am reading a text file to upload it into database. The text file contains like this with no headers...

> [10-10-2013 11:20:33.444 CDF] 1000020   Incident      T   This is the error message
>
> [10-10-2013 11:20:33.445 CDF] 1000020   Incident      T   This is the second error message

How can I store "10-10-2013 11:20:33" in Date Column and milliseconds 444 in integer column of database. Here if I try to use split with space first, it will split date into 3 parts. I want to get date between the brackets and then get the rest with split spaces.

Two points to mention here. 
1. Here we have spaces in between date column. 
2. Also I should be able to get other columns

Comment: Great. Its fine with me

Comment: @CPK_2011 is the date a fixed width?

Comment: Yes it is a fixed width

Comment: @CPK_2011 so given your specification you want it to split into columns as follow: column 1 `10-10-2013 11:20:33` column 2 `444` column 3 `1000020` column 4 `Incident T` column 5 `This is the error message` is that correct or do you want column 4 and 5 entirely splitted by spaces ?

Comment: Yes you are right. You got it perfectly. If Date can be shown as 10-10-2013 11:20:33 that would be fine. And only milliseconds in other column. First I explained the whole thing as one question with no answers. After I splitted the question, I have lost some meaning in it. Thank you. Waiting for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Admin, Please delete this post. I have copied the same answers to the related thread with their names mentioned. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real simplest way to do this is to use regular expressions, not gobs of split and indexof operations.

Regular expressions allow you to specify a pattern out of which pieces of a string can be extracted in a straightforward fashion. If the format changes, or there is some subtlety not initially accounted for, you can fix the problem by adjusting the expression, rather than rewriting a bunch of code.

Here's some documentation for regular expressions in .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

This is some sample code that'll probably do what you want. You may need to tweak a little to get the desired results.

```
var m = Regex.Match(currentLine, @"^\[(?<date>[^\]]*)\]\s+(?<int>[0-9]+)\s+(?<message>.*)\s*$");
if(m.Success) {
    // may need to do something fancier to parse the date, but that's an exercise for the reader
    var myDate = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["date"].Value);
    var myInt = int.Parse(m.Groups["int"].Value);
    var myMessage = m.Groups["message"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Regex works better. But the thing is I got very smart solution with Split function. The split function actually takes care of extracting the columns using this. allLines[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 5, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries). I want to use this Split function with Date format functionality both at the same time. I don't want use Regex for the Message or Date. For Date column I want to just check for spaces in between and take care of that and store properly in single date column with milliseconds in other column and the rest of all other columns the split will do.

Comment: @CPK_2011: Split is not a "very smart solution". It is a tedious, error-prone solution. Sure, you can get it to work. You could also parse character by character. But why do that? Why try to fit a square peg into a round hole? Just use regexes and be happier.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to just use `String.Split` and `String.Substring`

Generically I would do this:

```
//find the indices of the []
var leftIndex = currentLine.IndexOf("[");
var rightIndex = currentLine.IndexOf("]");

//this get's the date portion of the string
var dateSubstring = currentLine.Substring(leftIndex, rightIndex - leftIndex);

var dateParts = dateSubstring.Split(new char[] {'.'});

// get the datetime portion

var dateTime = dateParts[0];

var milliseconds = Int16.Parse(dateParts[1]);
```

**EDIT**

Since the date portion is fixed width you could just use `Substring` for everything.

Comment: Two points to mention here. 1. Here we have spaces in between. 2. Also I should be able to get other columns

Comment: @CPK_2011 please add this information to your question. That is not what you asked.