# Getting required information from Log file using Split

Tags: c#

I have a log file as follows

```
 [10-10-2013 10.10.10.333 CDF] Column2 Column3
 [11-10-2013 10.10.10.333 CDF] Column2 Column3
```

If I want to split the above log file by spaces first, it will split up to date first and then time and CDF and so on.

Is there any possible way to get whole first column [10-10-2013 10.10.10.333 CDF] as one column and then work on it.

Comment: Is there anything you've tried?

Comment: In general, changing the requirements after you've posted your question (especially after answers have been posted) is not cool. This one is kind of minor, but just be aware of that.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice, especially if it's only been a few hours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511905/simple-double-split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the info you've given us, you can just take a [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) from 0 to the [index of the `]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx).

```
string ExtractFirstColumn(line) {
    int index = line.IndexOf("]");
    string firstColumn = line.Substring(0, index + 1);
    return firstColumn;
}
```

That will give you the whole first column, as you asked for. You would then [do this for each line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx). Then, if these are all in a [single file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx), you can say:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(log);
var firstColumns = lines.Select(line => ExtractFirstColumn(line));
```

Then, if you need to [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) the first column, you can split on `' '`:

```
var tokens = firstColumn.Split(' ');
// tokens[0].Remove("[") is the data
// tokens[1] is the time
// tokens[2].Remove("]") is "CDF"
```

If you need more than the first column, as you're *now* indicating in your comments<sup>1</sup>, you'll have to move a little differently:

```
string[] ExtractColumns(string line) {
    int index = line.IndexOf("]");
    string firstColumn = line.Substring(0, index + 1);
    string[] lastTwoColumns = line.Substring(index + 2).Split(' ');
    return new string[] { firstColumn, lastTwoColumns[1], lastTwoColumns[2] };
}
```

I'm only going off the two examples you've given us, but I'd start with this very simple, maintainable approach absent new information.

<sup>1</sup>: This is why the [guidelines for how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) say to *be specific*.

Comment: For 2nd and 3rd columns how can I get it

Comment: @CPK_2011: Use the index of the `]` (`index` in my answer) and take the substring from `index + 2` to the [end of line](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/End_of_Line) and then split on `' '` (`line.Substring(index + 2).Split(' ')`). This only works if there are no spaces in `Column2` and `Column3`, something you've told us nothing about.

Comment: How I have to use the ExtractFirstColumn function

Comment: Obviously rewrite to return all of the columns as a `string[]` in the manner I just described.

Comment: Is it possible to use this in conjunction to your code items = allLines[i].Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 5, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); Because this solves most of my major problems

Comment: I find something is missing from my side to implement your code. There are some runtime errors at line. I don't know how to implement your code.

Comment: How should I call ExtractColumns function

Comment: By reading the lines from your log file and passing them to the function, one by one.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression to parse each line in order to retrieve the desired information:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    private static Regex regex = new Regex(
        @"\[([0-9\-]{10}) ([0-9\.]+) (.+)\] (.+) (.+)", 
        RegexOptions.Compiled
    );

    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("log.txt"))
        {
            string[] parts = regex.Split(line);
            Console.WriteLine(
                "date: {0}, ip: {1}, name: {2}, column 2: {3}, column 3: {4}", 
                parts[1], 
                parts[2], 
                parts[3], 
                parts[4], 
                parts[5]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is good. But I am not much used to Regular Expressions. I have the solution using Split and Substring. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the answer given by @siride

The real simplest way to do this is to use regular expressions, not gobs of split and indexof operations.

Regular expressions allow you to specify a pattern out of which pieces of a string can be extracted in a straightforward fashion. If the format changes, or there is some subtlety not initially accounted for, you can fix the problem by adjusting the expression, rather than rewriting a bunch of code.

Here's some documentation for regular expressions in .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

This is some sample code that'll probably do what you want. You may need to tweak a little to get the desired results.

```
var m = Regex.Match(currentLine, @"^\[(?<date>[^\]]*)\]\s+(?<int>[0-9]+)\s+(?    <message>.*)\s*$");
if(m.Success) {
// may need to do something fancier to parse the date, but that's an exercise for the reader
var myDate = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["date"].Value);
var myInt = int.Parse(m.Groups["int"].Value);
var myMessage = m.Groups["message"].Value;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The following is the answer given by @msarchet

The simplest way to do this is to just use String.Split and String.Substring

Generically I would do this:

```
//find the indices of the []
var leftIndex = currentLine.IndexOf("[");
var rightIndex = currentLine.IndexOf("]");

//this get's the date portion of the string
var dateSubstring = currentLine.Substring(leftIndex, rightIndex - leftIndex);

var dateParts = dateSubstring.Split(new char[] {'.'});

// get the datetime portion

var dateTime = dateParts[0];

var milliseconds = Int16.Parse(dateParts[1]);
```

EDIT

Since the date portion is fixed width you could just use Substring for everything.